# getJSON data to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get data from JSON via $.getJSON and assign it to a variable, so later I could iterate through it.
My code, as of now, looks like this:

```
var myJson;

$.getJSON("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ceQSpTWJTS?indent=2", function(json){
  if (json != null){
    console.log("Load successfull");
  };        
  myJson = json;
});

var main = document.getElementsByClassName("main");
var sec = document.getElementsByClassName("sec");
var entries = myJson.friends;

function myF_1(){
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {    
    main[i].innerHTML = entries[i].id;              
  }
};

function myF_2(){
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {    
    sec[i].innerHTML = entries[i].name;
  }
};

main.innerHTML = myF_1();
sec.innerHTML = myF_2();
```

Whereas I'm mostly positive that starting from `var main = document.getElementsByClassName("main");`, the code is correct (it worked before). 
The thing is, even the `$.getJSON` part seems to be okay. Console is returning `Load Successfull` like it's supposed to and all.
Error I'm getting is as follows: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'friends' of undefined`, so it's clearly something with my JSON. And my JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "56486b9a3fa6be06a434586a",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "0ae0d91a-f06e-4657-93a2-b36cdce9539c",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,013.92",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 35,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Gladys Davis",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "ZOINAGE",
    "email": "gladysdavis@zoinage.com",
    "phone": "+1 (980) 578-2162",
    "address": "942 Sandford Street, Bannock, Wyoming, 7863",
    "about": "Sit laboris est ut est duis aute occaecat do aliqua do elit in culpa. Elit deserunt anim consequat adipisicing sint. Id sit ullamco exercitation dolore ex fugiat minim Lorem sint voluptate.\r\n",
    "registered": "2014-07-18T01:02:49 -02:00",
    "latitude": -39.674779,
    "longitude": 91.675051,
    "tags": [
    "deserunt",
    "ex",
    "sunt",
    "ipsum",
    "sint",
    "culpa",
    "consectetur"
    ],
"friends": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Casandra Walter"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Wolf Medina"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Florine Osborne"
  }
],
"greeting": "Hello, Gladys Davis! You have 5 unread messages.",
"favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
},
```

I don't know what to do from here. Why `friends` is undefined?

Comment: firstly, it would be `myJson[0].friends`, secondly, `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, therefore, `myJson` will be undefined at the point where you are using it

Comment: After altering `var entries` to ` var entries = myJson[0].friends` I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` :(

Comment: you missed "secondly"

Comment: So, I gather then that I should declare the var outside the getJSON? But how?

Comment: no - see how this has been closed as duplicate - your answers may lie in the link that reveals all about the mysteries of working with asynchronous code in javascript :p